# failure to install library meinheld on MAC

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Heading

i trying to install meinheld using "python3 -m pip install meinheld" or "python3 -m pip install -U meinheld" and the result still got an error. can someone tell me what should i do for installing meinheld.

```
[my result still error][1]
```

Comment: Please show your error messages

Comment: You get an error message you don't understand. So you ask for help with it on SO. Welcome! We're happy to help. But you have to tell us *what the error message is* that you want help with. We can't guess. So [edit] your question and paste the error message, as text, not a picture, into it. It looks like you tried (and failed) to put a link to a screenshot into your question. Please don't do that. Questions on SO must be self-contained and not depend on off-site resources.